# Centering text in div while keeping a close button to the right side

Tags: html, css

I want the "Find Tenant" to be `vertical-align:middle` and completely `center`. Even with the "X" icon to the far right side.

But all I can get is this:

[image]

Here is my HTML

```
  <div class="book-find-tenant-head">
      Find Tenant
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()" style="float:right;">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">close</md-icon>
      </md-button>
  </div>
```

Here is my `book-find-tenant-head` class

```
.book-find-tenant-head {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', 'Arial Narrow'; 
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #337AB7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height:40px;
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: This question is quite common, you can use a pseudo element with vertical align middle. Search stack overflow and you find many examples

Comment: If you post the rest of your CSS, I can run a code snippet for you. Otherwise, what you want to do is absolutely position the "X" to the top left so it's outside of the layer collision. Then you can center the text and add padding or line height instead of vertical align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below css:

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kr27dw42/2/)

CSS:

```
.book-find-tenant-head {
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', 'Arial Narrow'; 
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #337AB7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
md-button.md-icon-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: the right:20px didnt work, it moved 20px to the left (very strange) anyway when I put it to 1px it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line-height` to vertically center the content, and `position: absolute` on the button to take it out of the document flow (and thus having no effect on horizontal centering of 'find tenant':

```css
.book-find-tenant-head {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', 'Arial Narrow';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30%;
  /* for demo */
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.md-icon-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-find-tenant-head">
  Find Tenant
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()">
    <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">close</md-icon>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox and absolute positioning is an option.

```css
.book-find-tenant-head {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif', 'Arial Narrow';
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 40px;
}

.md-icon-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-find-tenant-head">
  <span>Find Tenant</span>
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()">
    <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">close</md-icon>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ive seen that before, but I never understood what `flex` do? Can you teach a bit? and what are those?   `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` how are they different?